# Deciphering hex-codes as (probably) a timestamp

Tags: python, regex, hex

I'm parsing some logs that are very unclean and also all exist on one line per log-file.

I've managed to strip them apart with Regular Expressions, leaving me with only a weird HEX-like number and it's log-string. I think the sequence in the HEX-like number is the timestamp, but I can't figure out how to decipher it.

I was wondering if someone might see the pattern.

```
513328F8003D
51332900003D
5133290C003D
5133293C003D
51332945003D
5133294E003D
51332955003D
```

This is seconds later

```
5134519A102B
5134519C0039
513451B0132B
513451B3102B
513451B31329
513451B3182B
513451B31A2F
```

In a few occasions, the numbers are the same. But on around 28000 rows it only happens a few times. So I'm guessing it logs time per second, and thus in a very few cases generate an encoded timestamp on the exact same time, like this:

```
51345D391929
51345D391929
51345D3A042B
```

The update time of the log-file (except the double-time stated just above) is around 08:45 this morning.

Maybe it's some weird way of notating microtime? I can't figure it out :P

Comment: Any more hints? What date do you think this might be, for example?

Comment: Where are these logs from?

Comment: It might be server-time or local time. Local time would be around today 08:45 (2013-03-04 08:43 GMT+1). Server-time would be JST+0, but I'm not very sure. First I thought they were logcodes describing certain categories of logs, but then I noticed (counting the different ones) there we're like 25.000 different entries, and they all seemed to be sequential. That's why I based it on being a timestamp, as logical seen it can't be much else. It's about log-files of a game by the way. It's in a `HEXCODE::STRING`-format (pprint output: http://www.ghostsofthesun.com/output.txt)

Comment: About the linked file; the files are timestamped reversed, so per ~100 logs the next rows are older, but it's just to give as much info as possible. The number behind it is the occurrence, which is 2+ in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the leftmost four bytes are the timestamp:

```
In [29]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0x5134519A)
Out[29]: datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 4, 11, 47, 38)

In [30]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0x51332955)
Out[30]: datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 3, 14, 43, 33)
```

What is the maximum value of the rightmost two bytes? If they are not uniformly `0000-FFFF` it's unlikely it's just fractional seconds. And they're larger than `0x3e8`, so they can't be milliseconds.

Comment: Wonderful. That worked. I did these two: `0x51335B051329` followed by `0x51335B07003D`. It gave me `2013-03-03 15:15:33` and `2013-03-03 15:15:35`. The file's timestamp is: `March 03, 2013 03:17 PM`, so that's reasonable enough for me :). High precision isn't required. Thank you Pavel! :D

Comment: I just found out the last 4 HEX-digits are actually codes referring to what category the log entries are in :). Explaining why those make no sense in the date formatting ^^

Answer (score 5):

First, let's find the timestamp of 2013-03-04 08:43 GMT+1:

```
In [25]: import pytz
In [47]: gmt1 = pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT+1')

In [48]: import datetime as DT

In [49]: date = gmt1.localize(DT.datetime(2013, 3, 4, 8, 43))

In [50]: date
Out[50]: datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 4, 8, 43, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'Etc/GMT+1'>)

In [51]: import calendar

In [53]: calendar.timegm(date.utctimetuple())
Out[53]: 1362390180

In [54]: hex(calendar.timegm(date.utctimetuple()))
Out[54]: '0x51346ca4'
```

This has a promising similarity to the hex strings you posted.

---

So, if the last 4 hex digits are treated as a fractional part, the number can be interpreted as a UTC timestamp:

```
import datetime as DT
hexstamps = '''\
513328F8003D
51332900003D
5133290C003D
5133293C003D
51332945003D
5133294E003D
51332955003D
5134519A102B
5134519C0039
513451B0132B
513451B3102B
513451B31329
513451B3182B
513451B31A2F
51345D391929
51345D391929
51345D3A042B'''

for hexstamp in hexstamps.split():
    print(DT.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(int(hexstamp, 16))/16**4))
```

yields UTC datetimes:

```
2013-03-03 10:42:00.000931
2013-03-03 10:42:08.000931
2013-03-03 10:42:20.000931
2013-03-03 10:43:08.000931
2013-03-03 10:43:17.000931
2013-03-03 10:43:26.000931
2013-03-03 10:43:33.000931
2013-03-04 07:47:38.063156
2013-03-04 07:47:40.000870
2013-03-04 07:48:00.074875
2013-03-04 07:48:03.063156
2013-03-04 07:48:03.074844
2013-03-04 07:48:03.094406
2013-03-04 07:48:03.102280
2013-03-04 08:37:13.098282
2013-03-04 08:37:13.098282
2013-03-04 08:37:14.016281
```

Comment: Also wonderful unutbu! Wish I could accept all the answers :P. It's nice to see it can be done by different approaches. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like they're hex-encoded epoch timestamps ( well at least the first 8 characters look like they're a seconds-since-the-epoch, timestamp.

```
lines = """513328F8003D
51332900003D
5133290C003D
5133293C003D
51332945003D
5133294E003D
51332955003D
5134519A102B
5134519C0039
513451B0132B
513451B3102B
513451B31329
513451B3182B
513451B31A2F""".split("\n")

from datetime import datetime


def convert(x):
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp( eval("0x" + x.strip()[:-4] ) )        

for x in lines:
    print x, convert(x)
```

Gives....

```
513328F8003D 2013-03-03 10:42:00
51332900003D 2013-03-03 10:42:08
5133290C003D 2013-03-03 10:42:20
5133293C003D 2013-03-03 10:43:08
51332945003D 2013-03-03 10:43:17
5133294E003D 2013-03-03 10:43:26
51332955003D 2013-03-03 10:43:33
5134519A102B 2013-03-04 07:47:38
5134519C0039 2013-03-04 07:47:40
513451B0132B 2013-03-04 07:48:00
513451B3102B 2013-03-04 07:48:03
513451B31329 2013-03-04 07:48:03
513451B3182B 2013-03-04 07:48:03
```

I'd hazard a guess that the last four hex digits correspond to millisecond/microsecond part of the data but without exact values to compare I wouldn't try to guess how they're encoded. If you're happy with seconds looks like this might do the job though.

Cheers,

A.

Comment: Very well explained Andy, thank you very much! Milliseconds aren't very important, so this greatly suffices. Thanks yes again :D

Comment: Side note: `eval("0x" + x.strip()[:-4] )` is cleaner as the direct, safer and much faster `int(x.strip()[:-4], 16)`.

Comment: @EOL I misunderstand; do you mean int() is faster or eval()? :P

Comment: @Allendar: Sorry. :) I meant: `eval(…)` *should be written as* the direct, safer and much faster `int(…)`.